# Formating price value in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

my xml file has multiple plant tags in it. Basic code is:

```
<plant>
    <common>snakeroot</common>
    <botanical>cimicifuga</botanical>
    <zone>5</zone>
    <light>shade</light>
    <price>$5.63</price>
    <availability>071114</availability>
</plant>
```

I want to sort this file based on price. If i use
 `<xsl:sort select="//price" data-type="number" order="descending" />` 
but its not sorting and the reason is i have a dollar sign infront of it. Can someone advice on how to remove it or format it so that i get desired result.

Thanks

Comment: If you're using XPath 2, you can try: `select="price/substring-after( ., '$' )"`

But in general it's not a good idea to store the dollar sign in the XML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's always a dollar sign then you could do

```
<xsl:sort select="substring-after(price, '$')" data-type="number"
          order="descending" />
```

You definitely don't want the leading `//` as this makes it an *absolute* path which will pick out exactly the same sort key value for every single `plant` (namely the very first `price` element in the entire document), as opposed to a *relative* path to pick out a `price` from within the particular `plant` it's looking at at the time.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Yes it always have $ at the start. I'll try the code and let you know. Thanks @IanRoberts

Comment: I didn't actually wrote that way im using for-each to go through the plants and then just sorting it in there